# Show each row colums information php and sql

Tags: php, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to print the values of custom columns for all rows, I've got a sql developer file, i mean that i want to print some columns of every rows, if for example my table is named client and has name, subname and email i want to print every client name, subname and email I've found how to make it with mysql but I want to make it with php and sql developer.

The code I've shown only shows the first user name and not the rest names and other columns of other users.

```
<?php
function clientes($conexion) {
    $consulta = "SELECT NOMBRE FROM CLIENTE";
    $stmt = $conexion -> prepare($consulta);
    $stmt -> execute();
    return $stmt -> fetchColumn();
}

echo clientes($conexion);
?>
```

Comment: _"but i want to make it with php and sql developer"_ - What is "sql developer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to print every client name, subname and email i've found

Then you should use fetchall() this will fetch all the results as an array then iterate through the array and print each element of the array

```
function clientes($conexion) {
    $stmt = $conexion ->query("SELECT name,subname,email FROM CLIENTE")->fetchall();

  foreach($stmt as $row){

    echo "Client Name : ".$row['name']."<br>";
    echo "Client subname : ".$row['subname']."<br>";
    echo "Client email : ".$row['email']."<br>";
  }
}

clientes($conexion);
?>
```

Comment: @JoseLuis - I would recommend having one function that fetches the data and returns it as an array. It's never good to let functions do multiple things, since it's much harder to reuse them. Ex: if you want to output the same data in a different way on some other page, you need to create a new function for it. If it just returns an array, you can reuse the same function and just output it differently on different pages.

Answer (score 2):

You're only getting one column since you're explicitly only ask for one column (by using `fetchColumn()`) *and* the fact that you've only told SQL to return one single column.

Change your query:

```
// Replace column1 etc to the real column names
SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM CLIENTE
```

Then instead of using `fetchColumn()` (which is for fetching *one* column), use:

```
return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

and you should get an array containing associative arrays (one per row) with all three columns.

However, you have another issue:

```
echo clientes($conexion);
```

Since you're now returning an array, you can't just echo it straight off. If you do, you will get a warning about "Array to string conversion". You need to iterate through the array and output the data as you want it:

```
$data = clientes($conexion);

// Again, change the column names
foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo $row['column1'];
    echo $row['column2'];
    echo $row['column3'];
}
```

This will output all the data. You get to decide on the layout though.

Answer (score 0):

**For getting all columns**

You need to address your SQL Query different for it to work probably. At the moment you are only looking for the field `nombre`. Try to change it to:

```
  $consulta = "SELECT * FROM CLIENTE";
```

With the asterisk you calling all fields in the table `cliente`. For performance you should only call the fields your are needing. This would look like this:

```
  $consulta = "SELECT nombre,dni,sexo FROM CLIENTE";
```

---

**For getting all rows**

At the moment you just address one row here. You need to change your code to

```
return $stmt ->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Or better yet, just add the columns you want to fetch. If that table has a lot of columns with a lot of data, using `*` will come at a cost.

Comment: When i put an * it only shows user identification (DNI)

Comment: But the problem is that i just want to show all rows information and the code only shows first row

Comment: @JoseLuis - Since you're using `->fetchColumn()`, you will only get one value from the first column. Like it says in the manual: _"Returns a single column from the next row of a result set"_

Comment: @JoseLuis Try to use ->fetchAll()

Comment: @MagnusEriksson and how do it to show the rest of the columns and rows?

Comment: @arnebr it shows me the following error if i put fetchAll() Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\IISSI\Lives fitness\mostrarclientes.php on line 43
Array

Comment: @JoseLuis - That's because you can't echo arrays.